# How to display already guessed when the user repeat the letter?

Tags: python, for-loop

[How can I display if the letter is already input][1]

I'm trying to display and tells that the letter is already input and my problem that I wanted to display is already guessed when the letter repeats input by the user

```py
word = "Programming".upper()
errors = 5
guesses = []
game_over = False
print("Welcome to family feud")

while not game_over:
    for letter in word:
        if letter.lower() in guesses:
            print(letter, end="")
        else:
            print("_", end="")
            
    print("") 
    
    guess = input("Next Guess:")
    guesses.append(guess.lower())
         
    if guess.lower() not in word.lower():
        print("Wrong")
    game_over = True
    #here is the problem
    if guess in guesses:
        guesses.append(guess)
        print("You already input this letter")
    for letter in word:
        if letter.lower() not in guesses:
            game_over = False
if game_over:
    print(f"You won the Game! {word} !")
else:
    print(f"Game Over! The word was: {word}")
```

here is the compiler https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

I'm just a newbie using this stack overflow please forgive me if it's not specific enough

this is the picture I wanted to do
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cqgf.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store all guessed letters in the `guessed` list, and check if new guessed letter is in this list (`if guess in guessed`):

```
WORD = 'PROGRAMMING'
guessed = []
while True:
    guess = input('\nNext guess: ').upper()
    if guess in guessed:
        print('You already input this letter')
    elif guess in WORD:
        print('Correct!')
        guessed.append(guess)
    else:
        print('Wrong!')

    for letter in WORD:
        if letter in guessed:
            print(letter, end='')
        else:
            print('_', end='')

    if len(set(WORD)) == len(guessed):
        print('\nYou won the Game!')
        break
```

Output:

```
Next guess: r
Correct!
_R__R______
Next guess: g
Correct!
_R_GR_____G
Next guess: r
You already input this letter
_R_GR_____G
```

Comment: how can I add if he win the game, sorry just new in programming

Comment: may I ask, what is the purpose of the set function?

Comment: ‘set’ removes duplicated letters from word ‘PROGRAMMING’

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're putting `guess` to `guesses` and after that checking if `guess` is in `guesses`. Try to move it after that.

Something like:

```py
    if guess in guesses:
        guesses.append(guess)
        print("You already input this letter")

    guesses.append(guess.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

As Adam already stated, you are adding the current guess in the guesses list before checking if it was already there. Therefore, any guess you input will trigger the "You already input this letter" message.

Try this code:

```js
word = "Programming".upper()
errors = 5
error_count = 0
guesses = []
game_over = False
print("Welcome to family feud")

while not game_over:
    guess = input("Next guess: ")
    guess = guess.lower()
    if guess in guesses:
        print("You already input this letter")
    else:
        guesses.append(guess)

    for letter in word:
        if letter.lower() in guesses:
            print(letter, end="")
        else:
            print("_", end="")
            
    print("") 
         
    if guess not in word.lower():
        print("Wrong")
        error_count += 1

    if error_count == errors:
        game_over = True
    # Add extra parameter to exit the game if the word is complete
if game_over:
    print(f"You won the Game! {word} !")
else:
    print(f"Game Over! The word was: {word}")
```

Comment: how can I add if he win the game, sorry just new in programming

Comment: A very simple way would be to add a loop that checks the letters in guesses. Something like:

```lang-js

for letter in word: 
  if letter in guesses:
    check += 1
if check = len(word):
  break
```